# is it possible to chrome debug iife javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, breakpoints, iife

I've been running into this issue a lot recently. I go the source panel in chrome dev tools in order to debug some javascript. In the past I've clicked onto a line where I want the debugger to stop. The line number turns blue, then when I trigger the function call, the program stops and I can look at variables.

Recently I've run into a situation a couple time where I try to click into a function, but the display indicated I'm not setting a breakpoint. The thing that's common between both time is that I'm working with Immediately Invoked Function Expressions(IIFE). 
Is it possible to set breakpoints in a iife without access to the source code?

Comment: Did you try the `debugger` keyword ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned being able to set a breakpoint in an IIFE without access to the source code, so I setup two examples that you can try where you do not have access to source assuming you meant local disk. In either example, I was able to set a break point on any of the relevant IIFE lines and step into/over as expected using Chrome.

BTW - In neither example did I experience the behavior where Chrome did not set the breakpoint as expected.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamwaltuo/fu1pcwqf/

Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/khlmi6c2fezv0tn/iifetest.html?raw=1

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var i = 0;
                console.log("i = " + i++);
                console.log("i = " + i++);
            })();
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        Check the console
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've answered the question, "can i set breakpoints in iife in the chrome source window", thanks. now i have to figure out why i can't set breakpoints in these other windows...